# Django / Heroku Deploying - ModuleNotFoundError: "No module named 'django'"

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'` if I deploy my Django-Project to Heroku. Does anyone know why that is?

The complete log file, which comes after opening, is attached. I've been searching for several hours, but can't solve it...

```
    2021-04-24T21:54:55.188701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2021-04-24T21:54:59.835950+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn MPLoadManagement.wsgi --log-file -`
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.907766+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-24 21:55:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.908183+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-24 21:55:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3028 (4)
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.908277+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-24 21:55:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.909677+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/os.py:1023: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isnt supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.909678+00:00 app[web.1]: return io.open(fd, *args, **kwargs)
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.912935+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-24 21:55:02 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919805+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-24 21:55:02 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919807+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919817+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919818+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919818+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919818+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919819+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919819+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919820+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919820+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919820+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919821+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919821+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919821+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919822+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919822+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919823+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/MPLoadManagement/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919823+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919823+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.919969+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-24 21:55:02 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.953092+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-24 21:55:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2021-04-24T21:55:02.953195+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-24 21:55:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
    2021-04-24T21:55:03.019883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
    2021-04-24T21:55:03.124137+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**Requirements.txt**

```
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.3.1
astroid==2.5.2
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
certifi==2020.12.5
distlib==0.3.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1.7
django-autoslug==1.9.8
django-bootstrap-modal-forms==2.1.0
django-bootstrap4==2.3.1
django-crispy-forms==1.11.2
django-heroku==0.0.0
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.8
filelock==3.0.12
gunicorn==19.9.0
isort==5.8.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0
mccabe==0.6.1
pipenv==2020.11.15
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pylint==2.7.4
pytz==2021.1
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
toml==0.10.2
virtualenv==20.4.4
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
whitenoise==5.2.0
wrapt==1.12.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem now. It was because I hadn't created the static_root and staticfiles_storage folders which are neccesary for production-deploying

Answer (score 0):

In your requirements file change `psycopg2-binary` to just `psycopg2`

You are installing `django-heroku==0.0.0` is that what you really want?

Comment: I have changed it to "django-heroku==0.3.1" and "psycopg2==2.8.6". The initial versions are build automatically with "pip freeze > requirements.txt", therefore I assumed that they are correct. after the change, the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'" still appears in the logs

Comment: from my research it seems like some packages aren't installing correctly and it prevents either django or django-heroku from installing

Answer (score 0):

I've deployed more than 5 projects to Heroku and I have never faced like this error but it is obvious from the error message that Django is not installed probably, redeploy your project again and see if it works